# How to use a pox controller with a default controller in Mininet

Tags: network-programming, mininet, sdn, pox

I have a python script that aims to make a linear topology of length 2, with 2 controllers: a custom and standard pox. The ping between the hosts is not working and the only hint I have is: "You could rely on the L3_learning component documentation: ... "

```
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.topolib import TreeTopo
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.node import Controller, OVSSwitch
from os import environ

# DO NOT MODIFY THIS PART 

POXDIR = environ[ 'HOME' ] + '/pox'

class CustomPOX( Controller ):
    "Custom POX() subclass that connects defines the POX component to load"
    def __init__( self, name, cdir=POXDIR,
                  command='python pox.py',
                  cargs=( 'openflow.of_01 --port=%s '
                          'forwarding.l2_learning' ),
                  **kwargs ):
        Controller.__init__( self, name, cdir=cdir,
                             command=command,
                             cargs=cargs, **kwargs )

# controllers={ 'pox': POX }

class CustomSwitch( OVSSwitch ):
    "Custom Switch() subclass that connects to different controllers"
    def start( self, controllers ):
        return OVSSwitch.start( self, [ cmap[ self.name ] ] )


# THIS PART CAN BE CHANGED AND ADAPTED IF REQUIRED 

setLogLevel( 'info' )

def multiControllerNet():
   "Create a network from semi-scratch with multiple controllers."
c1 = CustomPOX ('pox', ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633)
c2 = Controller ('c2', port=6633)

cmap = {'s1': c1, 's2': c2}


net = Mininet( switch=CustomSwitch, build=False, waitConnected=True )

info( "*** Creating (reference) controllers\n" )
for c in [ c1, c2 ]:
    net.addController(c)

info( "*** Creating switches\n" )
s1 = net.addSwitch( 's1' )
s2 = net.addSwitch( 's2' )


info( "*** Creating hosts\n" )
h1 = net.addHost('host1', mac='00:00:00:00:10:01', ip='10.0.10.1/24')
h2 = net.addHost('host2', mac='00:00:00:00:20:01', ip='10.0.30.1/24')

info( "*** Creating links\n" )
net.addLink( s1, h1 )
net.addLink( s2, h2 )
net.addLink( s1, s2 )

info( "*** Starting network\n" )
net.build()
c1.start()
c2.start()
s1.start( [ c1 ] )
s2.start( [ c2 ] )

info( "*** Testing network\n" )
net.pingAll()

info( "*** Running CLI\n" )
CLI( net )

info( "*** Stopping network\n" )
net.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )  # for CLI output
    multiControllerNet()
```

The annotations are not mine

First of all, I'm not sure why the hosts can't communicate. Because 2 switches under two different controllers are not linked by default?

I tried to swap l2 with l3 but it doesn't change anything, which is normal since reading the documentation, I don't see what the advantage would be in this situation.
I tried to assign / change the ip addresses of the controllers but it had no effect.

Should I add a rule that the controllers must connect the switches? If so, is this topic ([How to add flow rules in POX controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832990/how-to-add-flow-rules-in-pox-controller)) the right solution? Because it doesn't seem to fit in the logic of my script.

Or is it more about changing / adding a parameter when I define my controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's just change l2 with l3 and add ip route in CLI ( host1 ip route add 10.0.30.0/24 dev host1-eth0 / host2 ip route add 10.0.10.0/24 dev host2-eth0 ).
L3 will broadcast if it don't know the host so -> connect with other switch.
After that: start pox controller and ping works !